# Jhipster code generator error jhipster --skip-client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm using this command to generate the jhipster code for server side only. but I am seeing an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`.

Here is the output

```
    Command:       jhipster --skip-client

INFO! Using bundled JHipster

   https://www.jhipster.tech
Welcome to JHipster v7.7.0

Application files will be generated in folder: D:\workspaces\personal\hipster\jhipster2
 _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

  Documentation for creating an application is at https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/
  If you find JHipster useful, consider sponsoring the project at https://opencollective.com/generator-jhipster
 _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

? Which *type* of application would you like to create

? Monolithic application (recommended for simple projects)

? What is the base name of your application? server

? Do you want to make it reactive with Spring WebFlux? Yes

? What is your default Java package name? com.mono.server

? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT authentication (stateless, with a 
token)

? Which *type* of database would you like to use? SQL (H2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, MSSQL)

? Which *production* database would you like to use? PostgreSQL

? Which *development* database would you like to use? H2 with in-memory persistence

? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Maven

? Do you want to use the JHipster Registry to configure, monitor and scale your application? No

? Which other technologies would you like to use? Elasticsearch as search engine, Apache Kafka as 
asynchronous messages
broker, API first development using OpenAPI-generator

? Would you like to enable internationalization support? Yes

? Please choose the native language of the application English

? Please choose additional languages to install Arabic (Libya)

? Besides JUnit and Jest, which testing frameworks would you like to use? Cypress, Gatling, Cucumber

? Would you like to install other generators from the JHipster **Marketplace? Yes**

? **Which other modules would you like to use? (generator-jhipster-gql-0.1.2) GraphQL integration for JHipster**

Unhandled promise rejection at:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**
```

Comment: Which version of nodejs, please run `node --version`? Also you pasted only error message, not the stack trace to show  which part of a the generator is failing.

Comment: >node --version
v14.15.4

Comment: This is the complete error message which I received while generating. @GaëlMarziou

Comment: Well you should try without generator-jhipster-gql module, maybe it has not been tested with latest JHipster. From its package.json, I can read that it was done with JHipster 7.0.1 https://github.com/glutengo/generator-jhipster-gql/blob/master/package.json#L32

Comment: Yes thank you it is working file without graphql

Comment: Great, I added an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 1):

You should try without generator-jhipster-gql module, maybe it has not been tested with latest JHipster 7.7.0.

From its package.json, I can read that it was done with JHipster 7.0.1

https://github.com/glutengo/generator-jhipster-gql/blob/5eee0aa909a1975fd51d7f006992f8f5cea23b88/package.json#L32

It's a common problem with JHipster modules, they are developed independently from JHipster core so they can lag behind.

You should open an issue in the gql module's project on github so that they know they have a compatibility issue.